# Using xcode to export code (newbie)?

Tags: xcode, export

So, I've written a short, simple c++ code (its a simple tic tac toe game). I was just wondering if there's a way to somehow export the code I've written from xcode, so that I would be able to say, send the file to someone who can then run it in their own terminal to play the game?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The code will be in text based source code files. If you look at the information provided by Xcode about the file, it will tell you where the file resides on our hard drive. Having said that, sending people the source code and expecting them to be able to run it is not really a good idea. You really need to compile the code into an executable and send that.

Comment: Alright, thanks. How exactly do I do that?

I looked within the folder that contains by xcode project and was able to locate the unix executable file, but when I clicked on it to run in terminal, it didn't function as it did when I compile it in xcode.